# Does 'interval' matter in FuncAnimation when saving to a file with a specified fps?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am using `FuncAnimation` to generate an animation which I am then saving to a `.gif` via `PillowWriter`. FuncAnimation can take an `interval` value which would normally define the time between frames if shown in the figure window, but PillowWriter takes a `fps` value which as far as I can tell overrides the interval. The code is roughly this:

```
anim = FuncAnimation(fig, myAnimateFunc, interval=100) #100ms = 10fps
writer = animation.PillowWriter(fps=30) #30fps = 33.3ms
anim.save('myAnimation.gif', writer)
```

The `.gif` file is definitely using the fps value from PillowWriter, but several tutorials about saving animations include the interval so I was confused. Does the interval matter at all if I'm specifying fps? Would decreasing it to `1` speed up render time by removing unnecessary downtime?